# Trouble parsing elif using PLY

Tags: python, yacc, bnf, ply

I'm continuing my journey into parsing using PLY. I've run into a problem when parsing `IF` and `ELSE IF` statements.

Here is my code, I've stripped out the irrelevant bits and just left it with the basics (this will run on Python 2.7).

```
from ply import lex, yacc

tokens = [
    'ELSE',
    'IF',
    'LPAREN',
    'RPAREN',
    'LCURLY',
    'RCURLY'
    ]


t_IF = r'IF'
t_ELSE = r'ELSE'
t_LPAREN = r'\('
t_RPAREN = r'\)'
t_LCURLY = r'\{'
t_RCURLY = r'\}'
t_ignore = '\r\t '


def t_error(t):
    print t


def t_newline(t):
    r'\n+'
    t.lexer.lineno += len(t.value)


def p_error(p):
    print ('error', p)


def p_empty(p):
    'empty :'
    p[0] = None


def p_if_statement(p):
    'if_statement : IF LPAREN RPAREN LCURLY RCURLY elif_statements_or_empty else_statement_or_empty'
    p[0] = ('if_statement', (p[6]))
    print p[0]


def p_else_statement(p):
    'else_statement : ELSE LCURLY RCURLY'
    p[0] = ('else_statement')


def p_else_statement_or_empty(p):
    '''else_statement_or_empty : else_statement
                               | empty'''
    p[0] = p[1]


def p_elif_statement(p):
    'elif_statement : ELSE IF LPAREN RPAREN LCURLY RCURLY'
    p[0] = ('elif_statement')


def p_elif_statements_1(p):
    'elif_statements : elif_statement'
    p[0] = [p[1]]


def p_elif_statements_2(p):
    'elif_statements : elif_statements elif_statement'
    p[0] = p[1] + [p[2]]


def p_elif_statements_or_empty(p):
    '''elif_statements_or_empty : elif_statements
                                | empty'''
    p[0] = p[1]


lexer = lex.lex()

s = 'IF(){}ELSE IF(){}ELSE{}'

parser = yacc.yacc(start='if_statement')
parser.parse(s)  # ('error', LexToken(LCURLY,'{',1,21))
```

Essentially, the problem is that I'm searching for an infinite amount of `elif_statement`s. When it encounters an `ELSE {`, it thinks that there is a parsing error because it expected an `IF` after the `ELSE`.

Is this what's called a "shift/reduce error"? What are some ways that I can resolve this?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the result of a shift/reduce conflict. PLY warns you that you have two of these, and they are both somewhat related to the `else` clauses.

However, the problem has nothing to do with the potentially infinite sequence of `else if` clauses. That is not a problem. The problem is more subtle and has to do with your use of empty productions.

The most important aspect of LR(1), from the point of view of figuring out issues, is that every non-terminal needs to be *reduced* (that is, created from its right-hand side) before the immediately following token is shifted. With that in mind, let's take a look at the grammar for `if_statement`:

```
if_statement : IF LPAREN RPAREN LCURLY RCURLY 
               elif_statements_or_empty
               else_statement_or_empty
```

and let's suppose that we have seen `IF(){}`, so the next token is `ELSE`. At this point in the right-hand side (which is the only active item in the parse at this point) we know that the next token must be either `ELSE` or the end of the input. In the latter case, it's clear what must be done: an `empty` must be reduced and then an `elif_statements_or_empty` must reduced from that `empty`; next another `empty` must be reduced and an `else_statement_or_empty` must be reduced from that `empty`. That all works.

But suppose the next token is `ELSE`. Now what? Since we cannot see any further than the `ELSE`, we don't know whether it is followed by `IF` or `(`. But we have to decide between two options:

1. *Reduce* an `empty` and then an `elif_statements_or_empty`. That will be correct if the `ELSE` is the beginning of `else_statement_or_empty` (which in this case cannot be empty).
2. *Shift* the `ELSE`, which can then only be the start of `elif_statements_or_empty`, which cannot be empty and thus must be `elif_statements`. That will be correct if the `ELSE` is part of an `ELSE IF` clause.

So that's one shift/reduce conflict. Bison always chooses the shift in a shift/reduce conflict, so it will assume that the first `ELSE` following the `IF` is the start of an `ELSE IF` clause. Let's continue with that assumption (which happens to be correct in the case of the provided input), and continue until we reach the following `ELSE`. We've now seen `IF(){}ELSE IF(){}` and we're again staring at an `ELSE`.

At this point, it is absolutely clear that `ELSE IF(){}` must be reduced to `else_if_statement` and it is also clear that `else_if_statement` must be reduced to `else_if_statements`. So far, so good. But now comes the problem. If there will be another `ELSE IF`, that's enough reducing and we should *shift* the `ELSE` to be part of the following `else_if_statement`. But if the `ELSE` is the start of the final `else_statement`, then we need to *reduce* the `else_if_statements` we just created into an `else_if_statements_or_empty`, since that reduction will be needed before we can shift the `ELSE` which starts `else_statement_or_empty`.

Again, bison always goes for the shift. But that means that it cannot ever decide to start an `else_statement_or_empty`.

---

So, what to do?

The first thing to note is that the `elif_statements_or_empty` production really is not adding any value at all. (Indeed, neither is the `empty` production, which I was going to just eliminate silently, but I'll leave this parenthetic obituary.) If we just put `elif_statements` in the `if_statement`, then we would not need to decide between `elif_statements` and `elif_statements_or_empty`. Of course, we would need `elif_statements` to match an empty string, but that's trivial: we just provide an empty right-hand side for the recursive base case. That is, instead of

```
elif_statements: elif_statement | elif_statements elif_statement
```

we will use

```
elif_statements: | elif_statements elif_statement
```

Instead of matching any number but at least one `elif_statement`, we will now match any number including zero `elif_statement`s. Which is exactly what we want.

Now that the `elif_statements` base case is empty, we no longer need to decide after the `IF(){}` whether or not we will have an empty set of `elif_statements`. We can just reduce an empty `elif_statements` and then see whether what comes next is an `elif_statement` or an `else_statement`. So with that simplification, we have actually eliminated both shift-reduce conflicts.

In summary, the new PLY file: (parser rules only, nothing else has changed):

```
def p_error(p):
    print ('error', p)

# Fixed to return both elif and else statements    
def p_if_statement(p):
    'if_statement : IF LPAREN RPAREN LCURLY RCURLY elif_statements else_statement'
    p[0] = ('if_statement', (p[6] + p[7]))
    print p[0]

# This needs to return a list because it could be empty
def p_else_statement(p):
    'else_statement : ELSE LCURLY RCURLY'
    p[0] = ['else_statement']

def p_elif_statement(p):
    'elif_statement : ELSE IF LPAREN RPAREN LCURLY RCURLY'
    p[0] = 'elif_statement'

def p_elif_statements(p):
    'elif_statements : elif_statements elif_statement'
    p[0] = p[1] + [p[2]]

# This handles both empty elif_statements and an empty else
# by reducing to an empty list
def p_empty(p):
    '''elif_statements : 
       else_statement  :'''
    p[0] = []
```

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive response. There is a problem with the solution proposed though, and that is that my `p_empty` is still being used for other things while parsing (I have a lot of `X_or_empty` rules). Under the proposed scheme, everything that was correctly returning `None` would now be returning an empty list. Is there another way to resolve the conflict without polluting `p_empty`?

Comment: @cmbasnett: It's just a name. Call it what you want. :) What matters is the grammar rule in the docstring; the name of the function is not used for anything, once ply decides that the function is relevant. But watch out for those x_or_empty rules; as with your question, they can get you into trouble.

Comment: I can't believe it took me over a year to get to actually implementing this! Other stuff just got in the way. Works like a charm now, thank you.